# POS with Magento integration with club/loyalty

Tags: sales, stores

We need a POS system that will integrate with Magento that will do the following:

- Inventory synchronization between Magento and POS (obviously).
- Layaway
- Barcode label maker.
- Import customers(w/ their existing IDs) from our POS because we have a membership/loyalty program and want to continue providing discounts. We need to scan that during checkout to identify the user and provide their discount. We don't need anything for membership card printing, we have our own ID maker(we print customer ID in a barcode on the card).

**Hardest part: We need to let members purchase membership online(print card later in store), check their balance online, and use their membership during online purchases.**
Our membership provides 10% off and has reward points(that are earned by buying things from our store).

Comment: Magento StackExchange is a forum that deals with concrete tech problems. You might get more relevant responses on http://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension as there are also merchants and solution specialsts on that forum

Comment: http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-pos-extension.html can use for Magento 2

Answer (score 2):

I do have some quick research on POS system for my store last week, and as far as I know, there's no POS system in the market supporting the features you bolded.

But you can ask your POS providers for the customization if the features is really necessary. I do ask SmartOSC for a customization on my X-POS, and pay an additional fee.
Take a look at their POS, I think it's good because it have all the thing you mentioned, except for the bolded part.

http://goo.gl/ajn66s

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you're looking for a quality cloud POS, then you should consider looking at LightSpeed Cloud POS or Revel Systems Cloud POS.  Both have benefits to what you're looking to achieve.  You'll have to determine which POS application best suites your business needs.

In regards to a Magento integraiton, look at Kosmos eSync.  You'll find a good You Tube video below.

The [Magento integration for Kosmos eSync](http://www.kosmoscentral.com/integrations/connect-magento) handles:

1) New Configurable Product Publishing to Magento & Updates
2) Simple Pr0duct Publishing & Updates
3) Order downloads to your Cloud POS
4) Adjustable Mappings 
5) Automated updates by the minute or hourly, how ever often you'd like to run your scheduled updates.
6) All synchronization is in Real Time, and your data isn't stored anywhere.  You don't have to worry about Privacy, Data Integrity or Hackers while your data is migrated because there's nothing on the hard drives to steel.
7) Dashboard is so easy to easy, even a Cave Man can use it!

Answer (score 1):

I see this extension can integrate with POS 
http://magegiant.com/magento-reward-points-extension/